# Custom Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop custom drop-down control.

I have placed a label below the html dropdown and have set the opacity of dropdown to zero. So that onclick of label, dropdown functionality will work.

But i am facing issues with IE6. Opacity is not being set to dropdown. Any suggestions??
Else, please suggest some idea to create a custom dropdown.

Comment: Show us your code pal. How do you expect us to know what is wrong?

Comment: That being said I am pretty sure ie6 does nto supprt opacity by default. You probably need jquery or something.

Answer (score 0):

`filter: alpha(opacity=50)` should work for IE5+

so, to cover all browsers, you could try

```
.transparentclass {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

probably not necessary, but you can also add

```
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
```

Comment: sure. but first post your code, so we can see if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for the >1.5% of people using ie6

I'm guessing you're looking for a css filter like this:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
```

or you could try `visibility:hidden`

I can't test either, because I don't have access to anything running ie6, but if they're using a browser 4 versions old they shouldn't be expecting the best experience anyhow, so you can try just showing ie6 a normal drop-down list and the enhanced version for better browsers.